# Is Sencha , JQuery Mobile using HTML 5 for their UI Design?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

Is Sencha , JQuery Mobile using HTML 5 for their UI Design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile incorporates some aspects of HTML5, like CSS3 and HTML "data-" attributes, as the [mention in their documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/about/features.html). Since they are still in alpha, I suspect their use of HTML5 features will only increase.

Comment: Is the stylish look of UI developed out of both these platforms mainly attributed to HTML5?

Comment: jQuery UI looked good before HTML5 (CSS3 in particular) existed. So, no, the appearance is not particularly due to HTML5. But they do use CSS3 where it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Sencha touch uses CSS3 for their animations and some UI elements (like gradients).

The theming is done via Sassy CSS.

HTML5 input fields are used or wrapped.

Sencha is not in Alpha, and their road map is [here](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/road-map/).